# Include tests from child suites when exporting test plans in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

When Exporting Test plan , i get plenty of Test Suites with 0 Test cases . 
Though Every one of those Test Suites have multiple Child Test Suites with Multiple Test cases each .

How am i able to include the Test cases from the Child Test Suite in the Exported Report ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works well in my side, the test case is located under corresponding test suite.

[image]

When you do the export through right click the test plan, please make sure you have selected ***`selected suite+children`***  and check the ***`test cases with step`***  option.

[image]

---

***Update:***

Simply select the test plan you want to export, and right click the test plan, select **Export**.

[image]

Comment: It doesnt give me this menu when i right click the Export Button , 
It just gives me the report,  is it possible you have "Enhanced Export PRO" Installed?

Comment: @YonnatanBar No I didn't install  this extension. This feature is provided by TFS. You just need the [**Test Manager**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web) extension to get the comprehensive set of testing features in your Visual Studio Team Services account/TFS server. This extension is included with Visual Studio Enterprise, MSDN Platforms and Test Professional subscriptions. If you do not have any of these subscriptions, then you will need to acquire or request a trial version from the Visual Studio Marketplace.

Comment: @YonnatanBar Besides, are you using VSTS or TFS on-premise. If you are using TFS, which version are you working on. My screen shot is captured by TFS2018, but it should also work on TFS2015 and above. I also add a more detail screenshot above shows how to export the test plan for your reference.